# Send jquery datatable column value to Javascript Function (Asp.Net MVC)

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I am binding data to jquery datatable in asp.net mvc, i have an anchor tag in one of the columns of the grid where i am accessing / reading row data and sending that data to a javascript function. The problem which i am facing is, i am able read and send row values to the function which are numbers for example ProductID="1" or CategoryID="3" , but if i try to send ProductName="Chai" to the javscript function i get an error in the console, and if i remove the parameter "ProductName" everything works fine and the javascript function also gets triggered.

**Following the console error:**

"Index:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: Chai is not defined
    at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick (Index:1)"

**Following is my Code:**

```
var BindDataTable = function (response) {
    $("#tbProduct").DataTable({
        "aaData": response,
        "aoColumns": [
            { "mData": "ProductID" },
            { "mData": "ProductName" },
            { "mData": "SupplierID" },
            { "mData": "SupplierName" },
            { "mData": "SupplierCountry" },
            { "mData": "CategoryID" },
            { "mData": "CategoryName" },
            { "mData": "QuantityPerUnit" },
            { "mData": "UnitPrice" },
            {
                "render": function (data, type, full, meta) {
                    return '<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal1" onclick="EditProduct(' + full.ProductID + ',' + full.SupplierID + ',' + full.CategoryID + ',' + full.ProductName + ')"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i></a>'
                }
            }
        ],
        "columnDefs": [
            {
                "targets": [2],
                "visible": false,
                "searchable": false
            },
            {
                "targets": [5],
                "visible": false,
                "searchable": false
            }
        ],
        "aaSorting": []
    });
}

var EditProduct = function (ProductID, SuppID, CatID,PrdName) {
    var url = "/Product/EditProduct?ProductID=" + ProductID + "&SuppID=" + SuppID + "&CatID=" + CatID;
    $("#myModalBodyDiv1").load(url, function () {
        $("#myModal1").modal("show");
    })
}
```

**Error:**
[image]

Comment: i think you are missing a quote at end : `+ full.ProductName + ')'+"`

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is that instead of playing around with that much string concatenations, what you can do is pass single object to your function and then use the required fields which needs to be passed as ajax call:

```
"render": function (data, type, full, meta) {
    return '<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal1" onclick="EditProduct('+full+')"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i></a>'
 }
```

and in your js function use it :

```
var EditProduct = function (product) {
    var url = "/Product/EditProduct?ProductID=" + product.ProductID+ "&SuppID=" + product.SupplierID + "&CatID=" + productCategoryID  + "&ProdName=" + product.Prooductname ;
```

Comment: thanks brother, but i tried as per your suggestion but still it didn't work
Now the console error says:
"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier"

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following approach in for passing string arguments to a JavaScript function:

```
<a onclick="javaScriptFunction(@p.ID, '@p.FileName');">@p.FileName</a>

function javaScriptFunction(id, fileName) {
    ...
}
```